# Standard presentation of the SE community

Tags: discussion

From time to time, some of us that are not affiliated with WRI, are invited (by WRI) to give a small presentation here and there (colleges, institutes, etc.), on the way we use their products, or to present products that we might have developed based on their technology (typically, presentation done on our hometown, our close-by).

Depending on the topic we are presenting, sometimes, there might be 5 or 10 min left at the end of our presentation, that we can just leave for the next presenter, or that we could fill-in with something different.

Presenting the SE community feels like a good idea:

- it is definitely inline with what the audience might want
- WRI staff is not going to do it for us

Could there be a standard presentation notebook for these occasions?

(these are typically single track 4 to 5 presentations events, and not exactly WTC, or EWTC, etc.)

It would be interesting to extract data from the site, on-live: number of users, visits, posts, locations, etc. (the usual stuff), but, although WRI does typically have a connection available, its quality cannot always be trusted (eventually, a presentation notebook that we just run/update, before going to the talk...).

What do you think? Can this be prepared, and be kept updated, by this community?

**EDIT**

By the way, anyone affiliated with WRI is more than welcomed to participate... (on my above text, I had no intention on ostracising you...)

Comment: This very same presentation might be useful for informing and recruiting new users of _Mathematica_ StackExchange. It could also encourage Wolfram Community developers to enhance their site, for example, by creating a reputation like mechanism to prioritize Wolfram Language bug fixes and development.

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock If I correctly understood, from a discussion I had with someone that looks at these things, some people don't like to participate on communities where's some sort of reputation or points tracking... and favour a more down to earth line of communication (I mean, with less rules, etc.). And it looks like WRI built there site based on exactly the opposite principles of the SE, and, most likely, to serve as an alternative channel. This is not to say that there's no possible improvement on the direction you mentioned...

Comment: I think that a good looking template, based on our design, and some chapters like: the history of the site, and its evolution, in posts and users, a list of the most relevant posts (the ones that are most useful to new users, and the most awesome), a brief talk on what a user can expect from the SE community (with an eventual mention of the diferences, in the sense of the complement that the W community brings), a mention of the major projects that kind of spinned off from this community (e.g. the packagedata), will probably already be good start.

Comment: First, you have a great idea! It might even inspire some more data collection, for example, how can you measure which posts the new users themselves find most useful? Second, it's a lot of work to identify bugs, find minimal examples, track them across different _Mathematica_ versions, follow up with Wolfram Support, etc. So some kind of Wolfram Community reputation system (perhaps not even public) might encourage more users to help out.